# Reference blob storage data in SQL azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I was just wondering if it is possible to reference azure blob storage data in a SQL Azure table column?

For example, say I have a table called Users in my SQL Azure database, one of the columns in that table is `UserImage`, and instead of creating `UserImage` as a `varbinary(MAX)` and storing the image data directly in the table, I would instead like to store the image data in blob storage, get a reference to the blob data and store that reference in the `UserImage` (`varchar`??) column in the database, and then somehow, when reading the rows from the Users table, access the associated image data from blob storage using the reference to that data.

I am asking this because blob storage is considerably cheaper to use than binary/blob data directly within SQL Azure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to store the URL to the image in SQL Azure and have the client program parse the URL and display the image from the URL.

I can't think of any way to have SQL Azure directly go to Blob storage, nor do I see a need for this as most client programs will be able to work with the URL as well as with the BLOB.

Comment: thank you very much. this is what I was asking for exactly, wasn't sure if it was a url or guid or something like this I could store in the table on sql azure, and then reference this url/identifier later to query blob storage to get the image.

Answer (score 6):

You should just store the image Url in SQL Azure, here is a short snippet to upload a image to the Blob Storage and get its Url:

```cs
    // Fake stream that contains your image to upload
    Stream data; 

    // Get a handle on account, create a blob service client and get container proxy
    var container = Account.CreateCloudBlobClient()
                        .GetContainerReference("my-fake-container");

    // Create a blob in container and upload image bytes to it
    var blob = container.GetBlobReference("my-fake-id");
    blob.Properties.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    blob.UploadFromStream(data);

    // Get your iage Url in the Blob storage
    var imageUrl = blob.Uri;
```

You now just have to store imageUrl in your row.

Answer (score 0):

Yes....You can do that by storing url in SQL Azure or some other place and then getting the url and passing it to the blob object

```
void DoSthWithBlob(Uri blobUri, StorageCredentials credentials){
    var blob = new CloudBlob(blobUri, credentials);
    blob.FetchAttributes();           
}
```